# Unable to save description in products with magento

Tags: magento, product, backend, updating

I got some problems when im trying to save product short and long description in backend.
whenever i try to change the description and press save, the text i have entered disappears and the textarea field is blank. This does not just only occur for the long and short description. The problem is for ALL textarea fields in the product edit page. I can change textarea fields in categories page and so on.

I have some PDO mysql error debug to show you..

```
SQL: SELECT `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `main_table`.`tax_calculation_rule_id`, `main_table`.`customer_tax_class_id`, `main_table`.`product_tax_class_id`, `rule`.`priority`, `rule`.`position`, `rate`.`rate` AS     `value`, `rate`.`tax_country_id`, `rate`.`tax_region_id`, `rate`.`tax_postcode`, `rate`.`tax_calculation_rate_id`, `rate`.`code`, IF(title_table.value IS NULL, rate.code, title_table.value) AS `title` FROM     `tax_calculation` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rule` AS `rule` ON `rule`.`tax_calculation_rule_id` = main_table.tax_calculation_rule_id
 INNER JOIN `tax_calculation_rate` AS `rate` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = main_table.tax_calculation_rate_id
 LEFT JOIN `tax_calculation_rate_title` AS `title_table` ON rate.tax_calculation_rate_id = title_table.tax_calculation_rate_id AND title_table.store_id = '0' WHERE (customer_tax_class_id = 3) AND (product_tax_class_id IN     ('7')) AND (rate.tax_country_id = 'SE') AND (rate.tax_region_id IN(0, 0)) AND (rate.zip_is_range IS NULL) AND (rate.tax_postcode IS NULL OR rate.tax_postcode IN('*', '', '', '*')) ORDER BY `priority` ASC,     `tax_calculation_rule_id` ASC, `tax_country_id` DESC, `tax_region_id` DESC, `tax_postcode` DESC, `value` DESC
AFF: 1
TIME: 0.0006
TRACE: #1 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql#0000000002b9780300000000842d8272#->_debugStat(2, 'SELECT `main_tab...', array(), &Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql#0000000002b97a2500000000842d8272#) called at [lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/    Mysql.php:424]
#2 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql#0000000002b9780300000000842d8272#->query(&Varien_Db_Select#0000000002b97ac200000000842d8272#, array()) called at [lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:734]
#3 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql[Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract]#0000000002b9780300000000842d8272#->fetchAll(&Varien_Db_Select#0000000002b97ac200000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.    php:341]
#4 Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation#0000000002b97ab100000000842d8272#->_getRates(&Varien_Object#0000000002b97a8900000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Resource/Calculation.php:99]
#5 Mage_Tax_Model_Resource_Calculation#0000000002b97ab100000000842d8272#->getRateInfo(&Varien_Object#0000000002b97a8900000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php:193]
#6 Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation#0000000002b97a8a00000000842d8272#->getRate(&Varien_Object#0000000002b97a8900000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php:412]
#7 Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation#0000000002b97a8a00000000842d8272#->_getRates(&Varien_Object#0000000002b97a8900000000842d8272#, 'product_class_id', 'PRODUCT') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php:420]
#8 Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation#0000000002b97a8a00000000842d8272#->getRatesForAllProductTaxClasses(&Varien_Object#0000000002b97a8900000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php:392]
#9 ET_CurrencyManager_Helper_Tax[Mage_Tax_Helper_Data]#0000000002b97b3000000000842d8272#->_getAllRatesByProductClass(&ET_CurrencyManager_Model_Store#0000000002b9782300000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Tax/    Helper/Data.php:376]
#10 ET_CurrencyManager_Helper_Tax[Mage_Tax_Helper_Data]#0000000002b97b3000000000842d8272#->getAllRatesByProductClass(&ET_CurrencyManager_Model_Store#0000000002b9782300000000842d8272#) called at [app/design/adminhtml/    default/default/template/catalog/product/js.phtml:45]
#11 include('/var/www/vb1/app...') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241]
#12 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Js[Mage_Core_Block_Template]#0000000002b97a6c00000000842d8272#->fetchView('adminhtml/defaul...') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272]
#13 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Js[Mage_Core_Block_Template]#0000000002b97a6c00000000842d8272#->renderView() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286]
#14 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Js[Mage_Core_Block_Template]#0000000002b97a6c00000000842d8272#->_toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php:81]
#15 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Js[Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template]#0000000002b97a6c00000000842d8272#->_toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863]
#16 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Js[Mage_Core_Block_Abstract]#0000000002b97a6c00000000842d8272#->toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php:43]
#17 Mage_Core_Block_Text_List#0000000002b97b0000000000842d8272#->_toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863]
#18 Mage_Core_Block_Text_List[Mage_Core_Block_Abstract]#0000000002b97b0000000000842d8272#->toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:582]
#19 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Core_Block_Abstract]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->_getChildHtml('js', true) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:526]
#20 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Core_Block_Abstract]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->getChildHtml('js') called at [app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml:82]
#21 include('/var/www/vb1/app...') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:241]
#22 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Core_Block_Template]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->fetchView('adminhtml/defaul...') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:272]
#23 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Core_Block_Template]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->renderView() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286]
#24 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Core_Block_Template]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->_toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php:81]
#25 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->_toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:863]
#26 Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page[Mage_Core_Block_Abstract]#0000000002b97b3b00000000842d8272#->toHtml() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555]
#27 Mage_Core_Model_Layout#0000000002b9783e00000000842d8272#->getOutput() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:390]
#28 Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action]#0000000002b978af00000000842d8272#->renderLayout() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php:269]
#29 Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController#0000000002b978af00000000842d8272#->editAction() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:419]
#30 Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action]#0000000002b978af00000000842d8272#->dispatch('edit') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250]
#31 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard]#0000000002b9785400000000842d8272#->match(&Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http#0000000002b9782000000000842d8272#) called at [app/code/    core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:176]
#32 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front#0000000002b9784a00000000842d8272#->dispatch() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354]
#33 Mage_Core_Model_App#0000000002b9781400000000842d8272#->run(array('scope_code' => '', 'scope_type' => 'store', 'options' => array())) called at [app/Mage.php:683]
#34 Mage::run('', 'store') called at [index.php:87]
```

**UPDATE:**
This problem started when we changed FCK editor to TinyMCE editor. I have also tried to reinstall fck and mce and no luck there.

Comment: In your debug I can see you use a plugin ET_CurrencyManager, if you turn it off (app/etc/modules/ET_CurrencyManager.xml) does the product save work?

Comment: I just tried to disable that module but the problem still exists. Any other ideas?

Comment: Out of the box, Magento doesn't have this problems, did you try to clear the cache? Do you get the same error?

Comment: I have tried to clear the cache many times and no success for the description issue

Answer (score 0):

First disable all extensions to make sure thats not the problem. It usually is. And disable it from System>Config>Advanced.

If that doesnt change anything, check your tax rules, rates and classes in Sales>Tax. Remove them all as you may have delete, and created a rule and maybe its a conflict.

Also, did you make any custom attributes related to tax or anything?

One last thing, based on your update. Go to System>Configuration>Content Management> and disable the wysiwyg editor.Try to update and save then.

Good luck